# Can't run node.js example project on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was trying run this example on the aws website for node.js http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/nodejs-express-hiking-v1.zip

from here

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-getstarted.html

(I tired the tutorial that had the same error)

502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.10.1

Is what is shown.

I also tried changing the port to 5000 but that did not help either.

Here are the logs:

I think the second one is the problem but I have no idea what to do about it.

---

### /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log

Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/

---

### /var/log/nginx/error.log

2017/02/20 04:10:25 [warn] 2488#0: duplicate MIME type "text/html" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf:42

---

### /var/log/eb-activity.log

```
  Did not find to find status of init job. Assuming stopped.
  Did not find to find status of init job. Assuming stopped.
[2017-02-20T04:10:21.090Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/20clean.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:21.285Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/20clean.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_base_dir
  + EB_APP_BASE_DIR=/var/app
  + rm -rf /var/app
[2017-02-20T04:10:21.286Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/30app_deploy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:22.003Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/30app_deploy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_base_dir
  + EB_APP_BASE_DIR=/var/app
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/tmp/deployment/application
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=/var/app/current
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user
  + EB_APP_USER=nodejs
  + mkdir /var/app
  + mv /tmp/deployment/application /var/app/current
  + chown -R nodejs:nodejs /var/app/current
[2017-02-20T04:10:22.003Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/40config_deploy.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:22.230Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/40config_deploy.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k config_staging_dir
  + EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR=/tmp/deployment/config
  ++ ls /tmp/deployment/config
  + for i in '$(ls $EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR)'
  ++ sed -e 's/#/\//g'
  ++ echo '#etc#init#nginx.conf'
  + FILE_NAME=/etc/init/nginx.conf
  + /bin/cp /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#init#nginx.conf /etc/init/nginx.conf
  + for i in '$(ls $EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR)'
  ++ sed -e 's/#/\//g'
  ++ echo '#etc#init#nodejs.conf'
  + FILE_NAME=/etc/init/nodejs.conf
  + /bin/cp /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#init#nodejs.conf /etc/init/nodejs.conf
  + for i in '$(ls $EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR)'
  ++ sed -e 's/#/\//g'
  ++ echo '#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf'
  + FILE_NAME=/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
  + /bin/cp /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
  + for i in '$(ls $EB_CONFIG_STAGING_DIR)'
  ++ sed -e 's/#/\//g'
  ++ echo '#etc#nginx#nginx.conf'
  + FILE_NAME=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  + /bin/cp /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
[2017-02-20T04:10:22.230Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/50start.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.232Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/50start.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action start-all
  nodejs start/running, process 2473
  nginx start/running, process 2488
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.232Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/60monitor_pids.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.794Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/60monitor_pids.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + '[' -d /etc/healthd ']'
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config optionsettings --namespace aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs --option-name ProxyServer
  + PROXY_SERVER=nginx
  + case "$PROXY_SERVER" in
  + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy nginx
  + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --name application --location /var/run/nodejs.pid
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.794Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/70restart_healthd.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.988Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/70restart_healthd.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + '[' -d /etc/healthd ']'
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config optionsettings --namespace aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs --option-name ProxyServer
  + PROXY_SERVER=nginx
  + '[' -f /var/elasticbeanstalk/healthd/current_proxy_server ']'
  + CURRENT_PROXY_SERVER=nginx
  + '[' nginx '!=' nginx ']'
  + echo nginx
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.988Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.988Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.988Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post.
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.989Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/PostInitHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.989Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1/PostInitHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/postinit.
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.989Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/StartupStage1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup stage 1 completed
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.989Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/AddonsAfter] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.990Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.990Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:26.163Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Disabled forced hourly log rotation.
[2017-02-20T04:10:26.164Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigLogRotation] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logpublish/hooks/config.
[2017-02-20T04:10:26.164Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:26.164Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:10:26.426Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Log streaming option setting is not specified, ignore cloudwatch logs setup.

  Disabled log streaming.
[2017-02-20T04:10:26.427Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/AddonsAfter/ConfigCWLAgent] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/addons/logstreaming/hooks/config.
[2017-02-20T04:10:26.427Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1/AddonsAfter] : Completed activity.
[2017-02-20T04:10:26.427Z] INFO  [2036]  - [Application deployment Sample Application@1] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application deployment - Command CMD-Startup succeeded
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.707Z] INFO  [3166]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] INFO  [3166]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] INFO  [3166]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] INFO  [3166]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] INFO  [3166]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...



-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
-------------------------------------




-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.232Z] INFO  [1745]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.234Z] INFO  [1745]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.234Z] INFO  [1745]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.234Z] DEBUG [1745]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::CloudFormation::Init||Infra-WriteApplication2||files..
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.237Z] DEBUG [1745]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||ManifestFileS3Key..
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.531Z] INFO  [1745]  : Finding latest manifest from bucket 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-648812771825' with prefix 'resources/environments/e-evnmznnmnr/_runtime/versions/manifest_'.
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.827Z] INFO  [1745]  : Found manifest with key 'resources/environments/e-evnmznnmnr/_runtime/versions/manifest_1487563665867'.
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.839Z] INFO  [1745]  : Updated manifest cache: deployment ID 1 and serial 1.
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.840Z] DEBUG [1745]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-PreInit.
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.840Z] INFO  [1745]  : Executing Initialization
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.841Z] INFO  [1745]  : Executing command: CMD-PreInit...
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.841Z] INFO  [1745]  : Executing command CMD-PreInit activities...
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.841Z] DEBUG [1745]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.841Z] INFO  [1745]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-PreInit...
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.841Z] DEBUG [1745]  : Running stages of Command CMD-PreInit from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.841Z] INFO  [1745]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-PreInit...
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.841Z] DEBUG [1745]  : Loaded 3 actions for stage 0.
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.841Z] INFO  [1745]  : Running 1 of 3 actions: InfraWriteConfig...
[2017-02-20T04:09:21.846Z] INFO  [1745]  : Running 2 of 3 actions: DownloadSourceBundle...
[2017-02-20T04:09:22.518Z] INFO  [1745]  : Running 3 of 3 actions: PreInitHook...
[2017-02-20T04:09:28.779Z] INFO  [1745]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-PreInit...
[2017-02-20T04:09:39.489Z] INFO  [1745]  : Command CMD-PreInit succeeded!
[2017-02-20T04:09:39.490Z] INFO  [1745]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.958Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.959Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.961Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-06a18c392aa73327c)..
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.961Z] INFO  [2036]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-06a18c392aa73327c)..
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.962Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.962Z] INFO  [2036]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.962Z] INFO  [2036]  : Received command CMD-Startup: {"execution_data":"{\"leader_election\":\"true\"}","instance_ids":["i-06a18c392aa73327c"],"command_name":"CMD-Startup","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"1e9fb2c8-f722-11e6-a999-2d00f4179ab5","command_timeout":"600"}
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.962Z] INFO  [2036]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.962Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.962Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.962Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.962Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.963Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.964Z] INFO  [2036]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.966Z] INFO  [2036]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.966Z] INFO  [2036]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-02-20T04:09:57.967Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Refreshing metadata...
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.389Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Refreshed environment metadata.
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.389Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.390Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.392Z] INFO  [2036]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.394Z] INFO  [2036]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.394Z] INFO  [2036]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.394Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-Startup.
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.395Z] INFO  [2036]  : Executing Application deployment
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.397Z] INFO  [2036]  : Executing command: CMD-Startup...
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.397Z] INFO  [2036]  : Executing command CMD-Startup activities...
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.397Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.397Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-Startup...
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.397Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Running stages of Command CMD-Startup from stage 0 to stage 1...
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.397Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-Startup...
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.397Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running leader election...
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.818Z] INFO  [2036]  : Instance is Leader.
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.818Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Loaded 7 actions for stage 0.
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.818Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running 1 of 7 actions: HealthdLogRotation...
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.830Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running 2 of 7 actions: HealthdHTTPDLogging...
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.831Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running 3 of 7 actions: HealthdNginxLogging...
[2017-02-20T04:09:58.832Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running 4 of 7 actions: EbExtensionPreBuild...
[2017-02-20T04:09:59.345Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running 5 of 7 actions: AppDeployPreHook...
[2017-02-20T04:10:15.101Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running 6 of 7 actions: EbExtensionPostBuild...
[2017-02-20T04:10:15.598Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running 7 of 7 actions: InfraCleanEbExtension...
[2017-02-20T04:10:15.602Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running stage 1 of command CMD-Startup...
[2017-02-20T04:10:15.602Z] DEBUG [2036]  : Loaded 3 actions for stage 1.
[2017-02-20T04:10:15.602Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running 1 of 3 actions: AppDeployEnactHook...
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.988Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running 2 of 3 actions: AppDeployPostHook...
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.989Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running 3 of 3 actions: PostInitHook...
[2017-02-20T04:10:25.989Z] INFO  [2036]  : Running AddonsAfter for command CMD-Startup...
[2017-02-20T04:10:26.427Z] INFO  [2036]  : Command CMD-Startup succeeded!
[2017-02-20T04:10:26.428Z] INFO  [2036]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"","returncode":0,"events":[]}]}
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.697Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.698Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.701Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-06a18c392aa73327c)..
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.701Z] INFO  [3166]  : Command is applicable to this instance (i-06a18c392aa73327c)..
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.701Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.702Z] INFO  [3166]  : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.702Z] INFO  [3166]  : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data":"{\"aws_access_key_id\":\"ASIAIYTXAC25BPPMVRGA\",\"signature\":\"jc+aHFw1y\\\/O+07rVpCPEOKb3iTs=\",\"security_token\":\"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\",\"policy\":\"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\"}","instance_ids":["i-06a18c392aa73327c"],"data":"9e0cfab0-f725-11e6-8f0e-9f392d16cbe4","command_name":"CMD-TailLogs","api_version":"1.0","resource_name":"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup","request_id":"9e0cfab0-f725-11e6-8f0e-9f392d16cbe4","command_timeout":"600"}
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.702Z] INFO  [3166]  : Command processor should execute command.
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.702Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Storing current stage..
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.702Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.702Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.702Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.703Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.704Z] INFO  [3166]  : Found enabled addons: ["logpublish", "logstreaming"].
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.706Z] INFO  [3166]  : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.706Z] INFO  [3166]  : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.707Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.707Z] INFO  [3166]  : Executing CMD-TailLogs
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.707Z] INFO  [3166]  : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] INFO  [3166]  : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Setting environment variables..
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] INFO  [3166]  : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] INFO  [3166]  : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] DEBUG [3166]  : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2017-02-20T04:32:43.708Z] INFO  [3166]  : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```